# Approximate solution to $\epsilon y'' + x^2 y' - \lambda y = 0$ near $x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-layer

I would like to approximate the solution of
$$\epsilon y''(x)+ x^2 y'(x) - \lambda y(x) = 0 $$
with boundary conditions $y'(0)=0$ and $y(\infty)=0$. The parameter $\epsilon$ is small.

To approach this problem, I have attempted to use a boundary layer approach. I consider that near $x=0$, the middle term is subdominant, so that $y_I(x) = A \cos ( \sqrt{\lambda}x).$ Likewise, for $x\rightarrow \infty$, I consider that the highest order term can be neglected, so that $y_O(x) = B \exp(-2\lambda/x)$.

Now each of these solutions matches its associated boundary condition -- $y'(0)=0$ for $y_I$, and $y(\infty)=0$ for $y_O$. However, the solution still contains two unrestrained constants.

How can I use the inner and outer solutions to solve for $A$ and $B$ and obtain an approximation for $y(x)$?

Comment: Shouldn't $y_I=A\cos (\sqrt{\frac \lambda \epsilon }x)$, which makes a problem?

Comment: The solution is obviously $y(x)=0$. Now one could ask if there are $\lambda$ with non-trivial solutions. This seems unlikely to decide with perturbation methods, as the stable inner solution is $C\exp(-\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\epsilon}}x)$, the left boundary condition giving $C=0$, and the outer solution $C'\exp(-\frac{\lambda}{x})$ is heavily singular at $x=0$ and converges to $C'$ for $x\to\infty$, requiring $C'=0$.

Comment: Although mathematicians don't like it, I know beforehand there is a solution with nontrivial lambda, because momentum conservation demands it : ) Thanks for correcting my inner solution

Comment: Lutz, do you think higher orders of the perturbation expansions in the inner and outer solutions could help match the solutions ?